# Testing Databases on the AWS Cloud (RedShift)?

Tags: testing, amazon-web-services, etl, business-intelligence, database-reconciliation

We have shifted from IBM DB2 databases to having PostGRE SQL databases on the AWS Cloud. Is anyone aware of or has worked with AWS to test databases?

```
a) If so, what tools do you use?
b) What do you test when checking the databases in a Business Intelligence (BI) type of environment?
```

Anything other than just load or performance testing on it. I wish to check on Functional Testing, where I validation/verify that the data on the Cloud Servers and Databases is equivalent to the Data in the physical Servers with DB2 as the database.

So, mainly a kind of data reconciliation, but with ETL also involved.

Answer (score 1):

Our product Ajilius (http://ajilius.com) does 90% of what you're after. We specialise in cloud data warehouse automation. PostgreSQL is our primary DBMS for on-premise and SMP data warehouses; Redshift is one of our cloud platforms (as well as Snowflake and Azure SQL Data Warehouse); and DB2 is a supported data source.

I say "90%" because our data warehouse migration feature reconciles data that is migrated between warehouses, but only when both warehouses were created by Ajilius. I'd like to understand more about your need, if you email me through our web site we can talk it over in detail.

Two competitors - Matillion and Treasure Data - also work in this space. Matillion is a full ETL tool, Treasure Data is more "EL" without the T. Definitely look at them, they're both good products with different approaches.